# phantomjs sumbitform login azure

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs to login to azure (my first day using phantomjs). I managed to get to the login page and enter my username, but to enter the password, you got to click next, but that doesnt happen

[image]

```
console.log("got here");
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.open("portal.azure.com", function(status) {
    console.log("azure website opened");

    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.evaluate(function() {
              document.querySelector("input[id='i0116']").value = "username";
              document.querySelector("idSIButton9").submit();
              document.querySelector("input[id='i0118']").value = "mypassword";
              document.querySelector("idSIButton9").submit();

              console.log("Login submitted!");
        });
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          page.render('colorwheel.png');
          phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ is that better?